# RewriteRule for example.com/cat1/cat2/?page=3

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, pagination

I want to create a webpage that catches:

```
http://example.com/category_name/subcategory_name/
```

to serve it with

```
http://example.com/page.php?label1=category_name&label2=subcategory_name&page=1
```

I created the following `RewriteRule` and it works

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=1 [L]
```

Now I want to catch

```
http://example.com/category_name/subcategory_name/?page=number
```

to serve it with

```
http://example.com/page.php?label1=category_name&label2=subcategory_name&page=number
```

I created the two following `RewriteRule`s but it does not work

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?page=([^/]+) /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=1 [L]
```

The server shows always the contents of `page=1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Aside:_ Why don't you go for URLs of the form `/category_name/subcategory_name/page` instead, rather than using a URL-parameter (query string) for the page number?

Comment: ... or `/category_name/subcategory_name/page/` if you are enforcing a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?page=([^/]+) /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=$3 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=1 [L]
> ```

You can't match the query string using the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument). This matches against the URL-path only. So this first rule never matches.

You don't need to explicitly pass the page "query string" into the *substitution*, since the query string can be passed through using the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag, you just need to confirm that there is (or is not) a `page` query string on the request to begin with.

If you are not expecting any other URL parameters then you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=\d+$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=1 [L]
```

The second rule checks there is no query string (ie. no `page` URL parameter), otherwise the presence of *any* query string (other than `page=<number>`) would trigger the same rule.

---

Alternatively, these could be combined into a single rule (avoiding repetition):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}@1 ^@(.)$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=%1 [L]
```

This rule *captures* the value of the `page` URL parameter (first *condition*) OR defaults to `1` if the query string is empty (second condition). The captured "page number" is then used in the *substitution* string with the `%1` backreference.

Note that with both solutions above, URLs of the form `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/bar/?page=1` return the same content. You could restrict this in the rule and/or redirect one to the other etc. Also, requests of the form `/foo/bar/?page=0` are valid.

---

OR, you could just default the value of the `page` URL param in your application (PHP) code if omitted (which you probably should be doing anyway) and simply pass the requested query string through (regardless of what it might contain). This would only require a single simplified rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Note the `QSA` flag, that will append (merge) any query string that is present on the initial request. Although this does not *validate* the URL (that is left for the application) so allows many more URLs through. eg. `/category_name/subcategory_name/?foo=1&page=2&bar=3` is permitted.

---

*Aside:* In comments I queried whether you should instead include the page-number in the URL-path, instead of the query string. eg. `/category/subcategory/page/`. This is arguably more "user friendly".

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:(\d+)/)?$ /page.php?label1=$1&label2=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

The last part of the regex `(?:(\d+)/)?` makes the page number optional.